# How do I fix this Pinch-like effect on such model with Subsurf modifier turned on?

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image]

How do make it so the area in the circle is not punched, and does not look distorted from certain angles?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a slight change in topology fixes a lot of it:

(yours in blue, mine green)

- Get the pole, (the 5-pointed vertex) off the angled edge, and on to a safe flat area, where it doesn't affect normal interpolation.
- Put a holding loop in the front-to-back axis, and another loop on the flat, around the frame
- Spread the curve-defining loops either side of the corner more evenly - in this case, they work better straightened out, I think.

[image]

When cutting sharp concave insets, corners, the secondary holding loops at a little distance, (like the one furthest to the left in the green topology) become quite important to keep the frame edges straight, and prevent new Catmull-Clark generated faces derived from large faces close to the corner 'leapfrogging': cutting the corner ahead of faces closer to it.

Maybe further improvements could be made by adding  a couple of edge loops to isolate the frame from the flat on the front.. (you could afford the polygons, I also reduced the Subdiv. from 5 to 2. :)

[image]

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide a loop, followed by <kbd>E</kbd> to make the loop parallel to the next loop on one side, and <kbd>F</kbd> to flip which side, is a very quick way to straighten existing loops, try out variations, as is <kbd>K</kbd> (knife) followed by <kbd>C</kbd> constrain to one of the 45 degree angles , followed by <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through the object: also handy when making repairs like this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to solve the topology thanks to your teachings.